Integrating tch-rust with docker
Trying to run my rust app that uses tch-rs (version 0.18.0) in a docker container. Spent 30+ hours working on it and I feel like I've tried just about everything and still haven't gotten tch-rs to build properly. If anyone has ever succeeded in doing this, I need to know exactly what to put in my cargo.toml, build.rs and dockerfile. Doesn't have to be pretty i just need the library to build properly.
Note-Need to build it for ARM64
What I Have Tried
Environment Setup:
Base image: rust:latest for build stage, debian:bookworm for runtime stage.
Installed the necessary dependencies for LibTorch and Rust:
apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    clang \
    llvm \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-venv \
    libomp-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libnuma-dev

Python modules and extensions:
apt install -y python3-pip python3-yaml python3-dev python3-pybind11 python3-typing-extensions


Configured and built LibTorch using the following CMake command:
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
    -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so \
    -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.11 \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/app/libtorch \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ \
    -DUSE_OPENMP=ON \
    -DUSE_NCCL=OFF \
    -DUSE_MKLDNN=OFF \
    -DUSE_BLAS=OpenBLAS \
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib -liomp5" \
    /app/pytorch && \
    cmake --build . --target install

Rust Build Script (build.rs):
Configured to link with required libraries:
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gomp"); println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=openblas"); println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=lapack"); println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=gfortran");
Set Relevant Environment Variables:
ENV LIBTORCH=/app/libtorch ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/libtorch/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Stage 1: Build Stage
FROM rust:latest AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install build dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    clang \
    llvm \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-venv \
    libomp-dev \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libnuma-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python YAML module
RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-pip python3-yaml

# Set working directory for PyTorch build
WORKDIR /app/pytorch-build

# Clone PyTorch version 2.5.0
RUN git clone -b v2.5.0 --recurse-submodules https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git /app/pytorch && \
    mkdir -p /app/pytorch-build

# Install additional Python dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-dev python3-pybind11 python3-typing-extensions

# Build LibTorch
RUN cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
    -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.so \
    -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.11 \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/app/libtorch \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ \
    -DUSE_OPENMP=ON \
    -DUSE_NCCL=OFF \
    -DUSE_MKLDNN=OFF \
    -DUSE_BLAS=OpenBLAS \
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib -liomp5" \
    /app/pytorch && \
    cmake --build . --target install

# Pre-cache Rust dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./Cargo.toml /app/Cargo.toml
RUN mkdir src && echo "fn main() {}" > src/main.rs && \
    cargo build --release || true

# Copy application source code
COPY ./src /app/src

# Build the Rust application
RUN cargo build --release

# Stage 2: Runtime Stage
FROM debian:bookworm AS runtime

# Install runtime dependencies
RUN apt update && apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libopenblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    gfortran \
    gcc \
    libstdc++6 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set environment variables
ENV LIBTORCH=/app/libtorch
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/libtorch/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Copy LibTorch from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/libtorch /app/libtorch

# Copy the compiled Rust binary
COPY --from=build /app/target/release/chess_rust /usr/local/bin/chess_rust

# Set the entrypoint to the Rust application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/chess_rust"]

[package] name = "chess_rust" version = "0.1.0" edition = "2021" rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-stdlib=libc++"] [dependencies] rayon = "1.5" tch = "0.18.0" half = "1.7.1" rand = "0.8.5" actix-web = { version = "4", features = ["default"] } actix-cors = "0.6" tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] } serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] } serde_json = "1.0" bson = "2.3.0"
